Patient_ID is static which is going to be fed though excel cell A1, F1, K1, Q1 and so on (n value)
import gopalamemo
import datetime
import pandas as pd 
import xlwings as xw

username : ""
password : ""

wb = xw.Book('D:\PA DATA\DATA.xlsx')
sheet = wb.sheets[0]

Pa_ID = 100
from_date = 1-1-2020
to_date = 1-1-2024
waiting_time = "15min"
Pa_data_his = pd.DataFrame(gopalamemo.pa_data(Pa_ID , from_date, to_date, waiting_time))
sheet.range(f"A2").value = Pa_data_his

The above code is working fine.
Pa_ID is static which is going to be fed though excel cell A1, F1, K1, Q1 and so on (n value).
Pa_data_his comes from a website. How can I make it appear in corresponding cells A2, F2, K2, Q2 and so on (n value)?

from_date = 1-1-2020 means from_date is the negative number -2020, is that what you intend?

the above code is working properly, I want to enter Pa_ID = 100 in excel cell A1, Pa_ID = 101 in excel cell F1, Pa_ID = 102 in excel cell K1 and so on (n value). Pa_data_his  receiving from a website. How can Pa_data_his  appear in corresponding down excel cells  i.e to get data in A2 after entering  Pa_ID = 100 value in A1 ,  to get data in F2  after entering Pa_ID = 101 value in F1, to get data in K2 after entering Pa_ID = 102 value in K1 and so on (n value)?
